# SQL query is right or wrong

Tags: sql, database, select

```
$query=tep_db_query("SELECT 
    o.orders_products_id
  , o.orders_products_filename 
  , o.orders_date
  , c.customers_id
  , c.customers_firstname
  , c.customers_lastname
  , c.customers_email_address  
FROM orders_products_download as o ,customers as c ,deviceid_ebcreader as d
WHERE (o.customers_id=c.customers_id) && (o.customers_id!=d.user_id) 
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
```

This is  giving 90K (approx) data. How I get only the selected data from databsae in my page.

Comment: Any query that uses commas in the `FROM` clause is wrong in my book, even if it happens to produce the right results.  Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The commas have been out of date for two decades.

Comment: You are retrieving information from three tables. Can you explain the join logic with the table deviceid_ebcreader? I see you are just using o.customers_id != d.user_id, which means that if d has for example 10 distinct values for user_id you will find 9 copies for each order

Comment: this is the query with joins: SELECT 
  o.orders_products_id, o.orders_products_filename, 
  o.orders_date, c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, 
  c.customers_lastname, c.customers_email_address 
FROM 
  orders_products_download as o 
  inner join customers as c on 
    o.customers_id = c.customers_id
  left / * or inner? * / join deviceid_ebcreader as d on 
    o.customers_id <> d.user_id / * so you take all the rows of d, excep... * /
LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}